# How powerful are Koharu Utatane and Homura Mitokado now?

Tags: naruto

Right now in Naruto universe, Koharu Utatane and Homura Mitokado are members of Konoha Council.

[image]

They joined the council after Hiruzen becomes The Third Hokage. According to naruto [Wiki:](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki)

> When Hiruzen became the Third Hokage, Homura and Koharu became his
>   councillors. With their years of experience and knowledge and their
>   unending effort to make Konohagakure a better place, they eventually
>   gained similar respect and social status as the Hokage himself.

But it is known that before that, they're member of [Team Tobirama](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Team_Tobirama), that also included Sarutobi Hizuren and Tobirama himself. They fought together during the First Shinobi War. So in this time their power could be compared to Hiruzen?

[image]

So, How strong are they now? Have they ever fought again after team Tobirama was dissolved?

Comment: They could be having a bunch of Sharingans and Hashirama's cells in their arms, lol. But seriously, it doesn't look likely that Kishimoto has any further role for them in the story. Good question though.

Comment: Indeed a good question but I think nothing from the manga explained or mentioned anything about their abilities. The answers could be merely speculations.

Comment: They are powerful politically, but have no impact in combat.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them were trained along with Hiruzen (the third hokage) by the first and second Hokage (Hashirama and Tobirama) so we can assume them to be quite powerful considering that they participated in the First Shinobi War as well. As of now, they weren't shown in combat at all, not when Kyubi attacked the village or not when Pain eradicated the village. I believe it'll be safe to assume that they have technical skill and experience that they have gained over the years but since unlike lady Chiyo, they don't use puppets or any other tool to help them in combat, they're pretty much off the floor.

Answer (score 0):

They're probably reasonably powerful, but it seems unlikely that they'd even be as powerful as Danzo was, and right now compared to the god-like power of Naruto, Sasuke, the Hokages, the Sage and his mum, their power is most likely basically insignificant.

Answer (score -1):

Years and years later...

Well, in my humble opinion they must be quite powerful. But, they must be "old school" shinobi. Some elemental jutsu, shurikenjutsu and overall ninja field skills. Danzo himself was, not taking his implants.

They being Councilors doesn't make them inoperable in field, actually. By their old age, maybe. But in their younger years, not probably. You see, by the series standards shinobi at their 50ies are still in "action". Orochi, Tsuna, Jiraiya are Databook recordists, stronger even than Kakashi at his 30ies, at least in their "total". Also, in the series, shinobi starts getting crampled in their physical stats at 65+. Like Chiyo and Hiruzen. Yet, both of them remained very skilled technicaly.

In my view, at their prime, Homura and Koharu must have been Top-level Jonin from Konohagakure, while Danzo and Hiruzen were Kage-material - actually Hiruzen had unprecedent talent and is a powerhouse shinobi even today. Also, they were elected by the Second Hokage to partake in his Escort Unite, said to be comprised only by Elite Ninja. Also, at the Nine-Tails attack, they were combat ready in the frontlines along Hiruzen and survived the ordeal, while many younger Jonin died at the claws of the fox.

Kagami Uchiha, said to be an exceptionally strong shinobi from the Uchiha clan died in the First Shinobi World War, with 25 years... not long after the mission we saw in Danzo's flashback.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! While this is an interesting perspective, we prefer answers to cite sources to back-up the information rather than subjection opinions